# print screen key in a chromebook?

Tags: keyboard, chromebook, crouton

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in a chromebook via crouton.

I want to print the screen but the chromebook doesn't have the F keys.

Comment: You could assign custom shortcut for that, or pin `gnome-screenshot` to the launcher as alternative. Let me know if you want that as a full answer

Comment: Yes, that could do the job. I don't want to go to open an application each time that I need a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Crouton, but this works on a Chromebook while in ChromeOS, as well as in Linux Beta--control key + "show all windows" key (5th key). It will take a screenshot, which you can then print.